# ruby operator precedence issue with shift operator

Tags: ruby

I had a general knowledge of [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence). It is the operator precedence chart. The shift operator has higher precedence than the logical operators (&& ||). I had a situation like this, where `arr` was an array and party was `nil`:

```
arr << party && party[3]
```

Now initially when I did this I thought if party was nil than party[] would never be called. Of course, since << has higher precedence it tries this first:

```
arr << party
```

But what happens next? Does ruby then do this:

```
arr << party[3]
```

Note that I used the highest operator () to resolve the issue:

```
arr << (party && party[3])
```

Comment: As a general practice it's good to use parenthesis to force precedence whenever you think an interpreter or compiler will not understand your expression. A language (like Ruby) might make them optional, but not using them can cause weird/unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<` operator on arrays returns the array. So if `party` is nil, `nil` gets pushed to `arr` and then `party[3]` is evaluated as part of boolean expression (because left part of the expression is truthy and didn't short-circuit). Since `party` is nil, an error will be raised here.

Actually, `<<` operator gets resolved to `<<` method of Array class. Which is very much like `push`. But it, being an operator, has different precedence, yes. If you were to use a method, it'd work more like you expect.

```
arr.push party && party[3] # => [nil]
arr.<< party && party[3] # => [nil]
```

Me, I put parentheses everywhere where there's even a shadow of doubt.

```
arr.push(party && party[3])
```

Also, not sure about intentions, but there might be a little bug in your code. The line above will always push *something* to `arr`. One of `false`, `nil` and `party[3]`. If you want to not do anything with a falsy value, then it's better to do something like this

```
arr << party[3] if party
```

Comment: Good answer. Personally, I think the shovel operator is more intuitive, and using it here would be fine using your alternative syntax: `arr << party[3] if party`.

Comment: "I put parentheses everywhere where there's even a shadow of doubt." Ditto. They don't cost anything and can save a lot of head pounding.